# tm combine list of corpora

Tags: r, list, tm

I have a list of URL for which i have fetched the webcontent, and included that into tm corpora:

```
library(tm)
library(XML)

link <- c(
"http://www.r-statistics.com/tag/hadley-wickham/",                                                      
"http://had.co.nz/",                                                                                    
"http://vita.had.co.nz/articles.html",                                                                  
"http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2010/09/the-r-files-hadley-wickham.html",                          
"http://www.analyticstory.com/hadley-wickham/"  
)               

create.corpus <- function(url.name){
doc=htmlParse(url.name)
parag=xpathSApply(doc,'//p',xmlValue)
if (length(parag)==0){
  parag="empty"
}
cc=Corpus(VectorSource(parag))
meta(cc,"link")=url.name
return(cc)
}

link=catch$url
cc <- lapply(link, create.corpus)
```

This gives me a "large list" of corpora, one for each URL. 
Combining them one by one works:

```
x=cc[[1]]
y=cc[[2]]
z=c(x,y,recursive=T) # preserved metadata
x;y;z
# A corpus with 8 text documents
# A corpus with 2 text documents
# A corpus with 10 text documents
```

But this becomes unfeasible for a list with a few thousand corpora. 
So how can a list of corpora be merged into one corpus while maintaining the meta data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `do.call` to call `c`:

```
do.call(function(...) c(..., recursive = TRUE), cc)
# A corpus with 155 text documents
```

Comment: Works! Never realized you could use (...) this way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `tm` offer any built-in function to join/merge many corpus. But after all a corpus is a list of document , so how the question is how to transform a list of list to a list. I would do create a new corpus using all documents , then assign meta manually:

```
y = Corpus(VectorSource(unlist(cc)))
meta(y,'link') = do.call(rbind,lapply(cc,meta))$link
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because `catch` is not defined, so I don't know exactly what that is supposed to do.

But now tm corpora can just be put into a vector to make one big corpora: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.7-1/topics/tm_combine

So maybe `c(unlist(cc))` would work.  I have no way to test if that would work though because your code doesn't run.